# node-zopfli error: Failed at the node-zopfli@1.4.0 install script

Tags: node.js, package, node-modules, package.json

while upgrading the node version from 8 to 12, node-zopfli installation is failing with below errors:

```
             from ../src/zopfli-binding.cc:1:
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2672:44: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
         V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
                                        ^~~~~~~~
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2672:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
            In file included from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
             from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:27,
             from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/node.h:63,
             from ../src/zopfli-binding.cc:1:
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2686:31: note: candidate: v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Isolate*) const
             Local<Object> ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
                           ^
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
 declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
 ^~~~~~~~~~
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2686:31: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
             Local<Object> ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
                           ^
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
  ^~~~~~~~~~
../src/zopfli-binding.cc:209:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToObject()’
const unsigned char * data = (const unsigned char*)Buffer::Data(inbuffer->ToObject());
                                                                                  ^
In file included from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/node.h:63:0,
             from ../src/zopfli-binding.cc:1:
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2672:44: note: candidate: 
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
                                        ^~~~~~~~
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2672:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
 In file included from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
             from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:27,
             from /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/node.h:63,
             from ../src/zopfli-binding.cc:1:
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2686:31: note: candidate: 
v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Isolate*) const
             Local<Object> ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
                           ^
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8.h:2686:31: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
             Local<Object> ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
                           ^
            /home/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
            zopfli.target.mk:143: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o' failed
            make: *** [Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o] Error 1
            make: Leaving directory '/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'
            gyp ERR! build error 
            gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
            gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
            gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-40-generic
            gyp ERR! command "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node" "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64"
            gyp ERR! cwd /home/node_modules/node-zopfli
            gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
            gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
            gyp ERR! not ok 
            node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
            node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node /home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64' (1)
            node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
            node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
            node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
            node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
            node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-40-generic
            node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node" "/home/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
            node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/node_modules/node-zopfli
            node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
            node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
            node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
            Failed to execute '/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node /home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64' (1)
            zopfli.target.mk:143: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o' failedl script
            make: *** [Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o] Error 1
            make: Leaving directory '/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'
            gyp ERR! build error 
            gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
            gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
            gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-40-generic
            gyp ERR! command "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node" "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=/home/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64"
            gyp ERR! cwd /home/node_modules/node-zopfli
            gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
            gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
            gyp ERR! not ok 
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
            npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

            npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
            npm ERR! errno 1
            npm ERR! node-zopfli@1.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
            npm ERR! Exit status 1
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! Failed at the node-zopfli@1.4.0 install script.
            npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2020-03-16T07_09_26_729Z-debug.log
```

It's showing the cache issue, checked after clearing the cache and tried updating the same as well as different packages. Still, the same issue is occurring. Is this due to version or anything else. Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked, and I don't have an explanation, but I do have a possible solution:

Try run:

```
npm install -g node-gyp@latest
npm update node-sass npm update node scripts
npm rebuild node-sass
npm install --build-from-source node-zopfli
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Now try to run the project.

I'm currently working on an old project. not sure why it's built the way it does, or what is it with node-zopfli@1.4.0, but I'm now able to run the project.